# The number of gaussian distributions in GMM？

Tags: image, algorithm, computer-vision, background-process, gaussian

i am working on background subtruction with GMM model, but confused. the most implement of the GMM model is EM_GMM, which models the background using K Gaussian and each pixel has a weight with each Gaussian, in other words, the image is modeled with K Gaussian. After i reviewing the paper written by stauffer "Adaptive background mixture models for real-time tracking", i think that each pixel has K
Gaussians, in other words, the image has n*K Gaussians totally, n is the pixel number in the image.
So ... i dont know if my thinking is right, for help...

Answer (score 0):

In general, the idea is to pretend that there is a random number generator which contains K gaussian distributions, and to generate a pixel at random you choose between the K distributions at random and then generate a random colour from the chosen distributions. The distributions do change as time goes on, but they only change very slowly, so large numbers of pixels share the same underlying distributions.

This is explained at the top of P 4 just before equation (5) "Every new pixel value, Xt, is checked against the existing K Gaussian distributions, until a match is found"

Comment: i think the GMM method proposed by Stauffer in the paper is different from EM GMM. The em gmm is used for Classification, and the GMM in Stauffer's paper is for background substruction. After reviewing the openCV source code of BackgroundSubstrcutionMOG2, the openCV using n*K gaussians for the image, in other words, K gaussian per pixel,  not each pixel sharing the same underlying K distributions. :-)